# Como colorir células de uma tabela com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ja fiz o codigo da tabela, porem não sei como colorir as colunas.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function tabela(){  

    var lin = prompt("linha");
    lin = parseInt(lin);
    var col = prompt("coluna");
    col = parseInt(col);

    var conteudo = "<table border = 0>";

        for (i=1;i<=lin;i++){

            conteudo += "<tr>";

                for (j=1;j<=col;j++){

                    conteudo += "<td>" + (i+","+j)+"</td>"

                }

            conteudo += "</tr>";
        }

    conteudo += "</table>"; 
    document.getElementById("tab").innerHTML = conteudo;

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="tab"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dei uma formatada no seu código, mas precisa arrumar a indentação e ver se realmente falta um `}` no final. Por favor, dê uma revisada no código se possível. Tirei umas linhas em branco apenas para evitar a necessidade de fazer scroll ao ler seu código. Para alterar/corrigir, basta um clique em [edit].

Answer (score 2):

Podes usar CSS para fazer isso:

```
td:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: yellow;
}
td:nth-child(even){
    background-color: green;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07q0dub2/

Se quiseres mesmo usar JavaScript podes fazer assim no loop interno:

```
for (j = 1; j <= col; j++) {
    var cor = (j % 2 == 0) ? 'green' : 'yellow';
    conteudo += "<td style=\"background-color:" + cor + ";\">" + (i + "," + j) + "</td>"
}
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/07q0dub2/2/